# Pegar nome do arquivo que não possui extensão usando foreach (glob())

Tags: php

Como pegar apenas arquivos sem extensão?

exemplos

1bdfe4baf9061c3667ded70d8f66142c

2a0daf2d8d5b7ea1813c7a84b146d092

91e3b288eab8d59598a52221296f8995

```
 $f=glob("*");
 foreach ($f as $arquivo) {
 echo "$arquivo<br>";
 }
 //Neste caso esta exibindo todos arquivos
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar:

- [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) para encontrar se o nome tem ponto (`.`)
- [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) para filtrar o array antes de iterar no `foreach`
- [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) para pegar somente o nome do arquivo

Ficaria algo como:

```
<?php

$arquivos = array_filter(glob('*'), function ($path) {
    return strpos(basename($path), '.') === false;
});

foreach ($arquivos as $arquivo) {
    echo "$arquivo<br>";
}
```

---

Entendi errado, removi esta parte:

<s>Pode usar o [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) assim:</s>

```
<?php

$arquivos = glob("*");

foreach ($arquivos as $arquivo) {
    $arquivo = pathinfo($arquivo, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

    echo "$arquivo<br>";
}
```